# SQL Server Wildcard Length

Tags: sql-server

I know that % will match for one or more characters, and that _ will match for only one character. Is there a way to have a wild card match for 5 or less characters? I could write code that searches for 1, 2,..,5 characters but this would be too much.

Here is an example

```
Select *
From MyTable
Where MyTable.[Content] like 'mystring%myotherstring'
```

I want % to match if there are 5 or 4 or 3 or 2 or 1 characters that separate "mystring" and "myotherstring". Any separation greater that 5 will not match.

Thanks!

Comment: Do you want to select columns where length of characters are 5 or equal to 5?

Comment: I have edited my post

Answer (score 3):

You could use the single character wildcard `_`:

```
SELECT *
FROM MyTable
WHERE
    Content LIKE 'mystring_myotherstring' OR
    Content LIKE 'mystring__myotherstring' OR
    Content LIKE 'mystring___myotherstring' OR
    Content LIKE 'mystring____myotherstring' OR
    Content LIKE 'mystring_____myotherstring';
```

Note that SQL server's enhanced `LIKE` operator does not support variable width wildcards.  Also, perhaps you wanted to place `%` at both ends of the `LIKE` expression, e.g.

```
WHERE Content LIKE '%mystring_myotherstring%'
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this to check the length of `substring` in between your known strings.

```
SELECT *
FROM MyTable
WHERE MyTable.[Content] LIKE 'mystring%myotherstring'
AND LEN(SUBSTRING([Content],LEN('mystring'), LEN([Content])-LEN('mystring') -LEN('myotherstring'))) <= 5
```